# Want to see all posts from friends on Facebook

Tags: facebook

Facebook now doesn't show me all my friends' updates, just what "it thinks" is my friend. I don't see posts on my timeline from people that I care about. I understand I need to change what appears on "edit options", but all I see is just "hide posts from" not "show posts from everyone". How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of settings you can adjust to change what and the order in which you see content in your news feed. In Facebook's [Controlling What You See in News Feed](https://www.facebook.com/help/335291769884272/) the first method suggested is changing how you **sort stories** in your news feed (in your case you would probably want "Most Recent" to see stories from all of your friends in order of recency):

> Use the Sort menu in the top right of your News Feed to choose which
>   stories you see first. Click **Most Recent** to see stories in the order
>   they were posted, or click **Top Stories** to see the most interesting
>   stories at the top of your News Feed.
>   [image: Sort facebook news feed]

You can also **Filter by friends list** (which it sounds like you do *not* want to do, so make sure this isn't selected)
Filter by friend lists

> Click one of your lists on the left side of your home page to see
>   stories just from the people on that list.
>   [image: Filter friends list for news feed]

As you mentioned you can also [hide or unhide stories](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/268028706671439?rdrhc).

You may want to check to make sure your settings include all stories since some users seem to have only close friends selected by default (see [Facebook Changes News Feed Settings, Some Users Only Shown Close Friends by Default](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2011/02/11/edit-news-feed-settings/)) I should note, however, that I wasn't able to find the interface shown below, so these adjustments likely are made in the previously mentioned sidebar where you can select sub-lists of friends

[image: Edit News Feed settings]

For the new news feed layout (circa April 2013 according to Mashable's [How to See EVERYTHING in Your Facebook News Feed](http://mashable.com/2013/04/02/facebook-news-feed-see-everything/)) the interface looks like this:

[image]

Comment: That didn't help me... I don't want just to rearange stories, I want more stories to appear! And the bottom panel ("edit your news feed") isn't showing at me aither... I don't have show post from...

Comment: @Ran right- so the way it works on FB by default is that certain posts (and not others) appear depending on how they are sorted, you can read more about it in Mashable's [How to See EVERYTHING in Your Facebook News Feed](http://mashable.com/2013/04/02/facebook-news-feed-see-everything/)

Comment: Although they describe exactly what I want - I don't have the arrow they are talking about... I hope "Most Recesent" will show me what I want...

Answer (score -2):

Go to "Home Page" > Scroll down left side > "Close Friends"(click) > right side ... "On the List ... see ... Add" > "ADD" those missing from posts.